# Pair bluetooth device from .net code?

Tags: .net, bluetooth

Well i want to write a simple application that would scan for a specific device and when found pair it without using a code, and when the device goes offline unpair it again, but i have no idea what library to use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) for working with bluetooth devices from .net

Comment: It seems that could work but i can't find a way to pair with a device without using a pairing code..